# ¿Cómo se puede diferenciar la suma de las columnas de dos tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas en una base de datos, `communities` y `daily_shares` y me gustaria hacer la differencia de la suma de la primera con la secunda:

```
INSERT INTO
        shares_diff (`date`, `shares_copylink`, `shares_email`, `shares_facebook`, `shares_messenger`, 
        `shares_pinterest`, `shares_twitter`, `shares_whatsapp`)
SELECT CURDATE() AS date,  
        SUM(shares_copylink) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares,
        SUM(shares_email) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_facebook) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_messenger) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_pinterest) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_twitter) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_whatsapp) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM daily_shares);
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '- SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares,
        SUM(shares_email) FROM communi' at line 5
```

Aqui esta [el schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caa7d1/1/0).

Utiliso MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle de la sintaxis es porque integras múltiples consultas pero no se especifica donde termina una y dónde inicia otra. Eso se soluciona agregando unos paréntesis en tus consultas, quedando tu resultado de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO
    shares_diff (`date`, `shares_copylink`, `shares_email`, `shares_facebook`, `shares_messenger`, 
    `shares_pinterest`, `shares_twitter`, `shares_whatsapp`)
SELECT
CURDATE() as date,
SUM(shares_copylink)-(SELECT SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares), 
SUM(shares_email)-(SELECT SUM(shares_email) FROM daily_shares), 
SUM(shares_facebook)-(SELECT SUM(shares_facebook) FROM daily_shares), 
SUM(shares_messenger)-(SELECT SUM(shares_messenger) FROM daily_shares), 
SUM(shares_pinterest)-(SELECT SUM(shares_pinterest) FROM daily_shares), 
SUM(shares_twitter)-(SELECT SUM(shares_twitter) FROM daily_shares), 
SUM(shares_whatsapp)-(SELECT SUM(shares_whatsapp) FROM daily_shares)
FROM communities
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM daily_shares);
```